# NextJS How to solve "Property ... does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ...'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

In my `nextjs`-app I have `Navbar`-component, where I pass the menu items as a props:

```
<Navbar navitems={navigationItems} />
```

the `navigationItems` is an array of objects.

then in the `Navbar`-component I have this:

```
export interface INavBarItem {
   id: string;
   text: string;
   path: {
     slug: string;
   };
}

export type INavBar = INavBarItem[];

const Navbar: React.FC<INavBar> = ({ navitems }) => { ... }
```

Now I get the error `Type error: Type '{ navitems: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & INavBar'.Property 'navitems' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & INavBar'.`

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is `navitems` in your interface? You have not defined it

Answer (score 0):

This is typescript so you need to explicitly type your props.

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface INavBarItem {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  path: {
    slug: string;
  };
}

export type INavBar = INavBarItem[];

const Navbar: React.FC<INavBar> = (navItems : INavBarItem[]) => {

  return (
    <div></div>
  )

}
```

You can't de-structure navitems from INavBar because it isn't a property of it. If you want to de-structure your props you need to use the names of properties that exist in your prop types.

But the error is that you can't pass an any type as props to your component.

Comment: Hmm, the error still appears...

Comment: Check out the edit. That should compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface INavBarItem {
   id: string;
   text: string;
   path: {
     slug: string;
   };
}

export type INavBar = INavBarItem[];

type Props = {
  navitems: INavBar;
}

const Navbar: React.FC<Props> = ({ navitems }) => { ... }
```